# How to load items in android homescreen listview widget?

Tags: android, listview, listviewitem, android-appwidget, homescreen

I am currently developing an Android project which makes use of a Homescreen Widget to display data to the user. The view that I used in the Widget is a `ListView`. Below are my codes:

**WidgetService Class**

```
public class WidgetService extends RemoteViewsService
{

    @Override
    public RemoteViewsFactory onGetViewFactory(Intent intent)
    {   
        return (new WidgetRemoteViewsFactory(this.getApplicationContext(), intent));
    }

}
```

**WidgetProvider Class**

```
public class WidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider
{   
    @Override
    public void onDeleted(Context context, int[] appWidgetIds)
    {
        super.onDeleted(context, appWidgetIds);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisabled(Context context) 
    {
        super.onDisabled(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void onEnabled(Context context) 
    {
        super.onEnabled(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        super.onReceive(context, intent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
            int[] appWidgetIds) 
    {
        for(int i=0;i<appWidgetIds.length;i++)
        {
            RemoteViews rv = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
                    R.layout.widget);

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, WidgetService.class);
            intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,
                    appWidgetIds[i]);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse(intent.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME)));

            rv.setRemoteAdapter(R.id.widgetListView, intent);

            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds[i], rv);
        }
        super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
    }
}
```

**WidgetRemoteViewsFactory Class**

```
public class WidgetRemoteViewsFactory implements RemoteViewsFactory
{
private Context context = null;
private int appWidgetId;

private List<String> widgetList = new ArrayList<String>();
private DBHelper dbhelper;

public WidgetRemoteViewsFactory(Context context, Intent intent)
{
    this.context = context;
    appWidgetId = intent.getIntExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,
            AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);
    Log.d("AppWidgetId", String.valueOf(appWidgetId));
    dbhelper = new DBHelper(this.context);
}

private void updateWidgetListView()
{
    String[] widgetFruitsArray = dbhelper.retrieveFruitsList();
    List<String> convertedToList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(widgetFruitsArray));
    this.widgetList = convertedToList;
}

@Override
public int getCount()
{
    return widgetList.size();
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position)
{
    return position;
}

@Override
public RemoteViews getLoadingView()
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public RemoteViews getViewAt(int position)
{
    Log.d("WidgetCreatingView", "WidgetCreatingView");
    RemoteViews remoteView = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
            R.layout.listview_row_item);

    Log.d("Loading", widgetList.get(position));
    remoteView.setTextViewText(R.id.listTV, widgetList.get(position));

    return remoteView;
}

@Override
public int getViewTypeCount()
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds()
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onCreate()
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    updateWidgetListView();
}

@Override
public void onDataSetChanged()
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    updateWidgetListView();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy()
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    widgetList.clear();
    dbhelper.close();
}
}
```

**Android Manifest File**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.listviewwithdb"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/MyTheme.Light" >

    <activity
        android:name="com.example.listviewwithdb.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver android:name="com.example.listviewwithdb.WidgetProvider" >
        <intent-filter >
            <action 
                android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
            android:resource="@xml/widgetinfo" />
    </receiver>

    <service
        android:name="com.example.listviewwithdb.WidgetService"
        android:exported="false"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_REMOTEVIEWS" />

</application>

</manifest>
```

The problem is that I can add the widget into the homescreen, but it displays the list of item in the listview with a "Loading.." message in it, I tried logging the values at `getViewAt()` as shown above and it displays the content that I want successfully. Is there anything that I'm missing in my codes that is causing the issue? Thanks for the help in advance

Comment: Hi, i am also getting the same problem. can u help me if you have got solution of it. can you send me the running code of this and ho to make kist item clickable? please help me if you have got solution of it

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have found out the issue. It turns out that I need to return the number of views, in which my case is 1, that I have in `getViewTypeCount()` in my WidgetRemoteViewsFactory class.

Comment: I'm having the same problem and our code is almost the same but I'm getting my data from a web service. I set my `getViewTypeCount` to return 1 as well but my `ListView` still doesn't show items. Can you help me? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39266206/items-on-listview-in-widget-doesnt-display-android Thanks.