# Items on ListView in Widget doesn't display [Android]

Tags: android, listview, widget

I create a `ListView` in my widget and getting the result from a web service. I don't have any problem in getting the result from the web service but the result is not displaying on my `ListView` and even `updatePeriodMillis` that updates the `widget` every 30 minutes is not working.

I'm following [this example](https://github.com/laaptu/appwidget-listview/tree/appwidget-listview1)  and added `AsyncTask` in the `ListProvider` class, I managed to get the result and instead of using the `populateListItem()`  where it is like this

```
 private void populateListItem() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        ListItem listItem = new ListItem();
        listItem.heading = "Heading" + i;
        listItem.content = i
                + " This is the content of the app widget listview.";
        listItemList.add(listItem);
    }
}
```

I use the code below in my `AsyncTask` on `onPostExecute`

```
 public class ListProvider implements RemoteViewsFactory {

  private ArrayList<ListItem> listItemList = new ArrayList<ListItem>();

  public ListProvider(Context context, Intent intent) {
       new GetJSONWebService().execute();
  }

 class GetJSONWebService extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {


 @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        String str = null;

        try
        {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(URL_STRING);
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
            str =  EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return str;

    }

  @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);

        try {

            JSONObject object = new JSONObject(result);
            JSONArray jArray  = object.getJSONArray("DATA");

            for (int i = 0, count = jArray.length(); i < count; i++) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

                    ListItem listItem = new ListItem();

                        listItem.heading = jsonObject.getString("name").toString();
                        listItem.content = jsonObject.getString("description").toString();
                        listItemList.add(listItem);


                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }




        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
 }
```

When debugging, it adds the items on my `listItemList` but it doesn't display on my widget `ListView`. How can I solve this? Thank you in advance.

---

Here is my `WidgetService`

```
public class WidgetService extends RemoteViewsService {

 @Override
  public RemoteViewsFactory onGetViewFactory(Intent intent) {
    return (new ListProvider(this.getApplicationContext(), intent));
  }
}
```

Here is my `AppWidgetProvider`

```
  public class WidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {

 @Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
                     int[] appWidgetIds) {

    final int N = appWidgetIds.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        RemoteViews remoteViews = updateWidgetListView(context,
                appWidgetIds[i]);
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds[i], remoteViews);

    }

    super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);

}

 private RemoteViews updateWidgetListView(Context context, int appWidgetId) {

    RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
            R.layout.widget_layout);
    Intent svcIntent = new Intent(context, WidgetService.class);
    svcIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);
   svcIntent.setData(Uri.parse(svcIntent.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME)));

    remoteViews.setRemoteAdapter(appWidgetId, R.id.listViewWidget,
            svcIntent);

    remoteViews.setEmptyView(R.id.listViewWidget, R.id.empty_view);

  return remoteViews;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve this by following [the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21614460/asyntask-with-remoteviews-in-stackview-widget) I found out that my `getCount` always returns 0 and therefore instead of using `AsyncTask` I put my web service call in `onDataSetChanged()`.

Answer (score 1):

did you added `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`?

Comment: I haven't use it. Where should I put it and how it works?

Comment: it shoud be called after you add content to your list. for example: in populateListItem() add it after the for loop.

Comment: Should I put `listItemList.notifyDataSetChanged()` ? Where `ArrayList<ListItem> listItemList = new ArrayList<ListItem>();`  Sorry I'm confuse.

Comment: no. if you use ListView, so you must set adapter to it. do you use adapter to show your list content?

Comment: My `Adapter` is my `ListProvider`

Comment: so try to call notifyDataSetChanged() from your ListProvider instance:

`provider.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Comment: It only gives me `notify()` and `notifyAll()` I tried doing like this `listProvider = new ListProvider(this.getApplicationContext(), intent);
        listProvider.notifyAll();`

Comment: try `listItemList.setRemoteViewsAdapter(intent)`

Comment: i don't know if i can help you but take a look here http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidWidgets/article.html